# I want the Erling code to determine the length of the visitor nickname

Tags: ejabberd, multiuserchat

I use the Ejabberd server .
How do I add the option to specify the number of characters of the visitor nickname within the room configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

I see no option to restrict the length of a room occupant nickname.

Comment: It is not in the ejabberd server but I want to add a new feature in mod_muc_room.erl

Comment: Some people use the length of the message and the status and the nickname to beat other people in the rooms or contacts using the application bombus and beat by xmlns

Answer (score 0):

This small patch limits the length of the occupants nicknames to 5 characters or less. It is not configurable, simply edit the source code:

```
diff --git a/src/mod_muc_room.erl b/src/mod_muc_room.erl
index ea2b069d7..bfc5b143a 100644
--- a/src/mod_muc_room.erl
+++ b/src/mod_muc_room.erl
@@ -1216,26 +1216,33 @@ do_process_presence(Nick, #presence{from = From, type = available, lang = Lang}
        case is_nick_change(From, Nick, StateData) of
        true ->
            case {nick_collision(From, Nick, StateData),
+             string:length(Nick) > 5,
              mod_muc:can_use_nick(StateData#state.server_host,
                           StateData#state.host,
                           From, Nick),
              {(StateData#state.config)#config.allow_visitor_nickchange,
               is_visitor(From, StateData)}} of
-           {_, _, {false, true}} ->
+           {_, true, _, _} ->
+               Packet1 = Packet#presence{sub_els = [#muc{}]},
+               ErrText = ?T("That nickname exceeds the maximum allowed length"),
+               Err = xmpp:err_conflict(ErrText, Lang),
+               ejabberd_router:route_error(Packet1, Err),
+               StateData;
+           {_, _, _, {false, true}} ->
                Packet1 = Packet#presence{sub_els = [#muc{}]},
                ErrText = ?T("Visitors are not allowed to change their "
                     "nicknames in this room"),
                Err = xmpp:err_not_allowed(ErrText, Lang),
                ejabberd_router:route_error(Packet1, Err),
                StateData;
-           {true, _, _} ->
+           {true, _, _, _} ->
                Packet1 = Packet#presence{sub_els = [#muc{}]},
                ErrText = ?T("That nickname is already in use by another "
                     "occupant"),
                Err = xmpp:err_conflict(ErrText, Lang),
                ejabberd_router:route_error(Packet1, Err),
                StateData;
-           {_, false, _} ->
+           {_, _, false, _} ->
                Packet1 = Packet#presence{sub_els = [#muc{}]},
                Err = case Nick of
                      <<>> ->
```